# How to merge two grouped-by Pandas Dataframes by a common column(ID) together?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by

I'm learning data analysis with pandas.

I have two grouped-by dataframes, looking like below.

df1:

```
        count1  count2  rate
id          
958     34  34  1.000000
2822    41  41  1.000000
5193    180 184 0.978261
5841    35  35  1.000000
5858    104 104 1.000000
```

df2:

```
    price
id  
958     170
2822    138
5193    160
5841    181
5858    250
```

How can I do `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['id'])`? Currently, since 'id' is the index, I can't select it.
Could someone help?

Comment: `pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), how='inner', on=['id'])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `join`

```
In [226]: df1.join(df2)
Out[226]:
      count1  count2      rate  price
id
958       34      34  1.000000    170
2822      41      41  1.000000    138
5193     180     184  0.978261    160
5841      35      35  1.000000    181
5858     104     104  1.000000    250
```

or `merge` by using `reset_index` of `df1`, `df2`

```
In [227]: pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), how='inner', on=['id'])
Out[227]:
     id  count1  count2      rate  price
0   958      34      34  1.000000    170
1  2822      41      41  1.000000    138
2  5193     180     184  0.978261    160
3  5841      35      35  1.000000    181
4  5858     104     104  1.000000    250
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. I spent hours for searching.. Your answer is very clear :) Really appreciated.